# C++ Program crashes when accessing object after copy

Tags: c++, pointers, deep-copy

I'm having a problem which I think is related to creating a copy of an object. I have a map class that contains a std::map with a bunch of classes defining the different tile types indexed by their ID, and a bunch of tiles in a vector each with a pointer to one of those classes. Additionally I have another class, Scenario, that contains the map.

The problem comes when I create a Scenario object and try to do anything with its map. There must be some problem when copying the pointers but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I have tried to reduce the code to what's necessary to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TileInfo {
    string name;

public:
    int id;
    TileInfo() {};
    TileInfo(int id, string name);

    string getName() const;
};

TileInfo::TileInfo(int id, string name)
{
    this->id = id;
    this->name = name;
}

string TileInfo::getName() const 
{
    return name;
}

class Tile
{
public:
    TileInfo* info;

    Tile() {};
    Tile(const Tile & other, map<int,TileInfo> & info);
    Tile (TileInfo* info);

    string getName() const;
};

Tile::Tile (TileInfo* tileInfo)
{
    this->info = tileInfo;
}

Tile::Tile( const Tile & other, map<int,TileInfo> & tileInfo )
{
    map<int,TileInfo>::iterator it = tileInfo.find(other.info->id);

    if(it == tileInfo.end())
        this->info = NULL;
    else
        this->info = &(it->second);
}

string Tile::getName() const 
{
    return info->getName();
}

class Map
{
    vector <vector <Tile>> tiles;
    map <int, TileInfo> tileInfo;

public:
    void print() const;

    Map() {};
    Map(map<int,TileInfo> tileInfo);
    Map(const Map & other);

    string getName() const;
    void loadTiles();
};

Map::Map(map<int,TileInfo> tileInfo)
{
    this->tileInfo = tileInfo;
}

Map::Map(const Map & other)
{
    this->tileInfo = other.tileInfo;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < other.tiles.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<Tile> line;

        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < other.tiles[i].size(); j++)
        {
            Tile tmpTile = Tile(other.tiles[i][j],tileInfo);
            line.push_back(tmpTile);
        }

        this->tiles.push_back(line);
    }
}

void Map::print() const
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < tiles[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << "Tile at " << i << ", " << j << " is a "; cout << tiles[i][j].getName() << endl;
        }
    }
}

void Map::loadTiles()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        vector <Tile> line;
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            map<int,TileInfo>::iterator ite = tileInfo.find(i);
            if( ite!=tileInfo.end())
                line.push_back(Tile(&(ite->second)));
            else
            {
                line.push_back(Tile(NULL));
            }
        }

        tiles.push_back(line);
    }
}

class Scenario
{
public:
    Map map;
    Scenario() {};
    Scenario(Map map);
};

Scenario::Scenario(Map map)
{
    this->map = map;
    this->map.print();
}

Map createMap()
{
    map<int,TileInfo> tmpInfo;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        tmpInfo.insert(pair<int,TileInfo>(i,TileInfo(i,"testname")));
    }

    Map rtrnVal = Map(tmpInfo);

    rtrnVal.loadTiles();

    return rtrnVal;
}

int main()
{
    Map newMap = createMap();

    Scenario newScenario = Scenario(newMap);
    newScenario.map.print();
    int input;
    cin >> input;
}
```

The print() at the end of the Scenario constructor prints the map's contents correctly, but the one after the scenario is assigned causes a crash. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's a lot of code, and you've not implemented copy constructors correctly, not checking for null pointers and all sort of *bad things*. You should debug your code using a debugger, it should reveal where the problems are occurring..

Comment: `Scenario* newScenario = new Scenario(newMap);`  and `newScenario->map.print();`please try.

Comment: Didn't see any error .Added your code here .http://ideone.com/ivVFwd

Comment: This is a hacked job to get the bug reproduced, I removed all verifications. I have implemented the Map(const Map & other) constructor. My logic was that it would copy over the other Map's tileInfo map and then populate the tiles with copies and point them to the new map by passing it by reference to the Tile(const Tile & other, map<int,TileInfo> & info) constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original std::map where your original `TileInfo` objects are stored is here:

```
map<int,TileInfo> tmpInfo;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    tmpInfo.insert(pair<int,TileInfo>(i,TileInfo(i,"testname")));
}
```

That is the map the houses the pairs. you then make a copy of said map. It creates copies of all your `TileInfo` objects, which is ok.

```
Map rtrnVal = Map(tmpInfo);
```

But this is where the wheels begin to come off. You fire `loadTiles` here, which sets up your map of vectors that addres the relative `TileInfo` objects in `rtrnVal`. This code:

```
rtrnVal.loadTiles();
```

leads to this code. Note that you're pushing the addresses of your mapped `TileInfo` objects into your vectors. The map where these reside is *this* objects map.

```
void Map::loadTiles()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        vector <Tile> line;
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            map<int,TileInfo>::iterator ite = tileInfo.find(i);
            if( ite!=tileInfo.end())
                line.push_back(Tile(&(ite->second)));
            else
            {
                line.push_back(Tile(NULL));
            }
        }

        tiles.push_back(line);
    }
}
```

Finally, back where we started you do this:

```
return rtrnVal;
```

**This makes a copy of the `Map`**, which makes a copy of the map of vectors, which contain pointers to the `TileInfo` in the map within `rtrnVal` that is about to be destroyed on function exit. The result back on the caller side.

```
Map newMap = createMap();
```

`newMap` now holds dangling pointers to `TileInfo` objects that were in `rtrnVal` in `createMap`.

**Possible Solution**

Rather than having a map of vectors containing pointers to `TileInfo`s, consider a map of vectors of *indexes*, where each index keys to a 0-based slot in a `TileInfo` `std::vector` that is contained along side the map. I can see what you were trying to do (singular `TileInfo`s shared across multiple cells) so you still reap that benefit. The vector will come along for the ride wherever the map does (they're owned by the same `Map` object) and copying won't harm anything because both the map (of indexes) and the vector (of `TileInfo`) will copy safely. In the end you still get what you want (singular `TileInfo`s) but now-indexed by number rather than pointer. As a bonus, you don't have to deal with rebasing pointers to TileInfo from one map to another in a custom copy-ctor. Its all relative (0.. n-1)

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably do it like that, but I thought the Map(const Map & other) constructor would be called when copying. My logic was that it would copy over the tileInfo map to the new object and then populate the tiles and point them to the new tileInfo map by passing it by reference to this constructor: Tile(const Tile & other, map<int,TileInfo> & info). It isn't working as I intended though so I'll probably just go with indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You're storing pointers to `TileInfo`:

```
class Tile
{
public:
    TileInfo* info;
    ...
```

But once the object is copied, the pointers are copied across, but the `TileInfo` that they pointed to have been destructed, so they are referencing invalid memory = crash.

Consider implementing the copy constructor / copy operator to handle it.

Comment: I have implemented the copy constructor for the Map but I forgot to implement the assignment operator, maybe that's why it's failing, I'll try it when I get home.